# Finite State Machine With Function Pointers

Tags: c++, state-machine

I am learning to use finite-state machines for some tasks but I am having problems navigating my state table and executing the functions to make it a useful system.

Consider my state machine:

[image: state machine]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/30/Automata_that_prints_the_first_word_of_each_line.png))</sub>

Explanation:
* = Print char to stdout
N = '\n'
S = ' '
A = aA-zZ

The code I started with from [Automata-based programming on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming) works for such a simple machine, but I want to modify it so that I can have a more robust state transition table and call functions based off those states.

I've posted [working basic code](https://pastebin.com/JiMCT8M3) at Pastebin, along with [the transtion table style I want to use](https://pastebin.com/pyHDN6eY).

I have not used pointers to functions before so I am not sure how to write the transition functions based off the data received by `process_event`. Eventually I would like to have a template that allows me to have state in/out & transition in/out functions so I can write complex user menus and even programming algorithms much more efficiently.

Comment: Interesting set up. What is your question?

Comment: My question is I am unsure how to implement my state machine to execute functions who's addresses are passed to it via the state transition table. (The second link)

Comment: I have a more complete version of my code now and a working program with some debugging output [HERE](http://pastebin.com/EET9Y9vZ). The main issue I am having is I can not assign an address to my function pointer without getting a compiler error (I'm using g++).

I am obviously doing something wrong but I don't get what...

Comment: Well I had a brain fart.. I had casting issues that I solved after enough re-work. I made a simple user interface with debug info [HERE](http://pastebin.com/1vK1Y7DN)

The downside to my design is its horribly clunky and you need to modify the StateMachine class, specificly the event processor to handle a new kind of interaction.

I would use BOOST::FSM but this is going on an ARM microcontroller so I need to write my own

Comment: [The difference between Programmers.SE and SO](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: Ahh, after doing some more poking around I kind of felt that was the case. Forgive my noobery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using functions as states is very powerful, but using transition tables is *very* error prone and painful compared to using recursive functions (function states that return functions).  A fantastic implementation for you to consider is the [quantum hierarchical statem machine](http://www.state-machine.com/).  Although it is only about 1000 lines of code as a base, it has [an accompanying book](http://www.state-machine.com/psicc2/index.php) to explain any question you might have about how it works.  Very powerful, very fast.

Comment: I have looked at Quantums products before but they seemed a bit complex and I had no idea about that book. I will take a closer look at it now. I still want to write my own for the sake of learning and because I would like my own version that's similar across c++, Java and embedded platforms.

Comment: @uMinded: The Quantum library is already ported to every language you will encounter, embedded or otherwise.  The sournce/implementation is so concise, that you will easily be able to modify it for your own purposes, as if it was your own code.  And no state-machine implementation is as thoroughly documented as this one.  It is a sure bet.

Comment: You can remove the all errorproneness of transition tables and actually make it super robust by leverage the preprocessor which has late binding. E.g. one place: `"define STATE_LIST STATE_LIST_ENTRY(A) STATE_LIST_ENTRY(B) STATE_LIST_ENTRY(C) ...` and then (temporarely) define the entry macro where used, e.g `#define STATE_LIST_ENTRY(s) #s, \n char *state_names[] = {STATE_LIST}; \n #undef STATE_LIST_ENTRY". This way you can guarantee that if you later add or remove a state it is applied everywhere. The same applies for the transition events/signals.

Comment: And bonus: you can enforce consistent naming on the state functions by combining state and event in the function name.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check
[Boost.msm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html) - A very high-performance library for expressive UML2 finite state machines.

Read documentation, because it is all about managing complexity about statemachines.

There is also other state machine implementation in boost that you might prefer because it compiles faster since it is not designed for super speed (which does not means that it is not fast enough) [Boost.Statechart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html) - Arbitrarily complex finite state machines can be implemented in easily readable and maintainable C++ code.

As Brent Arias mentioned you should read book from http://www.state-machine.com/psicc2/index.php It is state machines bible.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the one to that book!

I have not used many of BOOST's features before and just recently discovered its meta programming facilities. I am going for clear and concise code that is easier to read than for speed when I'm running on a desktop environment.

Comment: I am going to read the material above then I'm going to lay out the structure of my code as I would like to implement it in psudo code, then implement it a piece at a time. What is the appropriate stackExchange site to do this on?

Comment: I think that is not about how you want your state machines library look like, but opposite. How you want code that uses this library look like.

Comment: As other people besides me will be using my FSM implementation to use my program I need the interface to be extremely readable even from a non code standpoint. This is one of those odd times where speed means nothing and its all just for organized looks

Answer (score 1):

Your compilation issue saying that it could not convert from `int` to `void (*)(int)` was from the branch struct:

```
struct branch
{
    int event_type:3;
    enum states state_new:2;
    int do_func:1;
};
```

The `do_func` is defined as an integer and not `void (*do_func)(int)`;

Comment: Indeed, I found this out after looking over the code 10 times and not seeing it. I finally remembered I had it declared in the structure.